# Problem with evidence parameters in breeze

Tags: scala, linear-algebra, implicit, scala-breeze

I'm trying to build a DenseMatrix of Vectors in breeze. However I keep getting the error message:

```
could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type breeze.storage.Zero[breeze.linalg.DenseVector[Double]]
```

for the line:

```
  val som: DenseMatrix[DenseVector[Double]] = DenseMatrix.tabulate(5, 5){ (i, j) => DenseVector.rand(20)}
```

Even though doing something similar with a Scala Array works fine:

```
val som = Array.tabulate(5, 5)((i, j) => DenseVector.rand(20))
```

I'm not sure what it is I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing? To be honest I don't understand what the error message is telling me... I don't do enough Scala programming to understand this? What even is an Evidence parameter and can I explicitly specify it or do I need an implicit?

Comment: you are trying to create a dense matrix where each element is a dense vector. Is that where you are trying to do?, or do you want to create a matrix stacking dense vectors?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to create a DenseMatrix when each element is a DenseVector. I can do it with an Array, or I can do it converting that array into a DenseMatrix. In case you are wondering, I'm implanting a form of neural network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `DenseMatrix.tabulate[V]` firstly fills the matrix with zeroes. So there should be an instance of type class `Zero` for `V`, i.e. in our case for `DenseVector[Double]`. You can define it yourself e.g.

```
implicit def denseVectorZero[V: Zero : ClassTag]: Zero[DenseVector[V]] =
  new Zero(DenseVector.zeros(0))
```

i.e. if we know `Zero` for `V` then we know `Zero` for `DenseVector[V]`.

Or even easier

```
implicit def ev[V: ClassTag]: Zero[DenseVector[V]] = new Zero(DenseVector(Array.empty))
```