# Can't create Breeze DenseMatrix with Scala3

Tags: scala, implicit, scala-breeze

When trying to create a dense matrix of type Option with Scala 3 I receive an error.

```
  val dm1 = DenseMatrix((1,2),(1,2))   // <- this works
  val dm2 = DenseMatrix((Some(1),Some(2)),(Some(1),Some(2)))  <- doesn't work
```

Error: no implicit argument of type breeze.storage.Zero[V] was found for parameter zero of method apply in trait MatrixConstructors

Btw, it  is working in Scastie and Scala 2.

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/89HUyuXNQrqWDPNpRbtrOw

Comment: The 2nd line doesn't compile in Scala 2.13.9 either https://scastie.scala-lang.org/7bQBBfLVT6eJSQPnIffsoA

Comment: i added the scastie link

Comment: Ok, if you look at my scastie. I create a vector and then a matrix from it. Works in Scastie but wont work in my Scala project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add necessary implicit

```
implicit val optIntZero: Zero[Option[Int]] = Zero(Some(0))
implicit val someIntZero: Zero[Some[Int]] = Zero(Some(0))
```

or more generally

```
implicit def optZero[A](implicit zero: Zero[A]): Zero[Option[A]] = Zero(Some(zero.zero))
implicit def someZero[A](implicit zero: Zero[A]): Zero[Some[A]] = Zero(Some(zero.zero))
```

or just

```
implicit def someZero[F[t] >: Some[t], A](implicit zero: Zero[A]): Zero[F[A]] = Zero(Some(zero.zero))
```

[Problem with evidence parameters in breeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72642470/problem-with-evidence-parameters-in-breeze/)

Answer (score 1):

Another easy approach. Create a "simple type" matrix and map to to the target type.

```
val v = DenseVector(1, 1, 1)
val dm1 = DenseMatrix(v,v)
val dm2 = dm1.map( Some(_))
```